# How can I Login to spring cloud Config Server using Hashicorp vault?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

I am currently working on a spring boot microservice application, with a centralized config via the spring cloud config server so that many clients (as services) can access their property files from the spring cloud config server. I decided to secure access to the config server (via spring security with credentials stored in a database). I also saved all database connection details (usernames, passwords, etc for the services), and other login credentials in Hashicorp Vault and was able to connect the spring cloud config server to vault. However, I am not able to login each config client to the config server using the corresponding credentials for each client via Vault. For the config server, the `application.yml` is:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: git, vault
    
    data:
        mongodb:
            uri: mongodb+srv://${DB_NAME}:${DB_PASS}@myMongoHost

    application:
        name: config-server
    cloud:
        config:
            username: ${CONFIG_SERVER_USERNAME}
            password: ${CONFIG_SERVER_PASSWORD}
            server:
                vault:
                    host: 127.0.0.1
                    port: 8200
                    scheme: http
                    authentication: TOKEN
                    token: 
                    order: 1
                    # kv:
                    # enabled: true
                    profile-separator: '/'
                    backend: secret
                    kvVersion: 2
                git:
                    uri: https://github.com/my-config-server
                    default-label: main
                    username: ${GIT_USER}
                    password: ${GIT_PASSWORD}
                    order: 2
```

For a given client, the  `application.yml` as follows:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: configclient
```

while the `bootstrap.yml`for the config client is given by:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    config:
      token: mytoken
      # uri: http://localhost:8888
  config:
  
      import: configserver:http://${CONFIG_SERVER_USERNAME}:{CONFIG_SERVER_PASSWORD}@${app.config-server.host}:${app.config-server.port}
```

The login credentials for the configclient is saved using a key/value  pair in Vault as follows:

```
{
CONFIG_SERVER_USERNAME: myConfigServerUsername
CONFIG_SERVER_PASSWORD: myPassword 
}
```

It is not possible to load the properties for each client using

```
${CONFIG_SERVER_USERNAME}:${CONFIG_SERVER_PASSWORD}@${app.config-server.host}:${app.config-server.port}
```

But the client was able to connect and fetch its properties when I replaced the above connection url with

```
myConfigServerUsername:myPassword@${app.config-server.host}:${app.config-server.port}
```

My question is: how can I get the clients to connect to the config-server using credentials stored in Vault using  `${CONFIG_SERVER_USERNAME}` and  `${CONFIG_SERVER_PASSWORD}` instead of hard coding the username and password into the either the config server or the configclient's `application.yml` or `bootstrap.yml` file? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The devil is in the details. Thanks for providing us with the secret layout, but please show the full output of `vault kv get --format json path/to/the/credential`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. if I run ```path/to/the/service-name```, I get the key/values for secrets. But ```path/to/the(service-name/usernamekey/ ```returns null.

Comment: Thanks. ```path/to/the/service-name```, I get the key/values for secrets. ``` {
  "request_id": "d93c7489-f2bb.-.....",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "CONFIG_SERVER_PWD": "myPassword",
      "CONFIG_SERVER_USR": "myConfigServerUsername",
      "service_PASS": "myPassword",
      "service_USERNAME": "myUsername"
    },
  .....
  },
  "warnings": null
} ``` But ```path/to/the/service-name/usernamekey/ ```returns null.

Comment: Thanks, but next time **edit your question** instead of adding comments. Welcome to StackOverflow . Storing username and password together like you do is a good practice, but you should store each credential in its own entry. Edit your question to show how you currently use the secrets in your `application.properties` file. +Do you have any code that makes Spring look for properties values in Vault?

Comment: It is also unclear what your plan is. It should be: Login to Vault (with an AppRole, K8S or cloud integration). Then read credentials to the config server and log in to it. Then read connection strings from it. Read database credentials from Vault for that connection and then log in to the database.

Comment: Sure thanks. I will edit it and provide mode details. And will check AppRole etc.

Comment: AppRole did not do the trick. And I edited the question.